# SSRS report from XML data source / Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to do a SSRS report based from XML file with SQL Server / BIDS 2008. I have never tried this before, so most likely it's just something stupid that I have missed. I tried to do it based on these examples:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964129%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

My XML is really simple:

```
<Customers>
    <Customer ID="1">
        <Name>Bob</Name>
        <Orders>
            <Order ID="1" Qty="6">Chair</Order>
            <Order ID="2" Qty="1">Table</Order>
        </Orders>
        <Returns>
            <Return ID="1" Qty="2">Chair</Return>
        </Returns>
    </Customer>
</Customers>
```

And I have used empty string at the query, <Query></Query>, and "Customers/Customer" which all work in the Designer, but I still get the same error.

Data source definitions:

[image: Data Source Definitions]

Query Designer shows the data fine:

[image: Query Designer]

But when trying to go forward in the wizard, I get this error:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely there's something wrong with my Visual Studio setup. Found another PC where I was able to test this and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the bug in Report wizard user interface. Here you can find explanations from Microsoft about this issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/525419/ssrs-2008-r2-report-project-wizard-ui-exception

Alternative way to solve the problem is to create report without Report wizard.